# why Hadoop shuffling time takes longer than expected

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to figure out which steps takes how much time in simple hadoop wordcount example.
In this example 3 maps and 1 reducer is used where each map generates ~7MB shuffle data. I have a cluster which is connected via 1Gb switches. When I look at the job details, realized that shuffling takes ~7 sec after all map tasks are completed wich is more than expected to transfer such a small data. What could be the reason behind this? Thanks

Comment: After couple hours of debugging, I think I found the reason for 7 sec shuffling time. When reduce task is ready to fetch intermediate data, it checks if any of intermediate data is ready to be fetched, if not, then it waits hard-coded 5secs then check again as `if (numInFlight == 0 && numScheduled == 0) { reporter.progress(); Thread.sleep(5000); }`

Answer (score 1):

The transfer is not the only thing to complete after the map step. Each mapper outputs their part of a given split locally and sorts it. The reducer that is tasked with a particular split then gathers the parts from each mapper output, each requiring a transfer of 7 MB. The reducer then has to merge these segments into a final sorted file.

Honestly though, the scale you are testing on is absolutely tiny. I don't know all the parts of the Hadoop shuffle step, which I understand has some involved details, but you shouldn't expect performance of such small files to be indicative of actual performance on larger files.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop uses heartbeats to communicate with nodes. By default hadoop uses minimal heartbeat interval equals to 3seconds. Consequently hadoop completes your task within two heartbeats (roughly 6 seconds).

More details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1906

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already user heartbeat interval 300ms in MRConstants.java as `code` public static final int HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MIN = 300;

Answer (score 0):

I think the shuffling started after first mapper started. But waited for the next two mappers.

There is option to start reduce phase (begins with shuffling) after all the mappers were finished. But that's not really speed up anything.

(BTW. 7 seconds is considered fast in Hadoop. Hadoop is poor in performance. Especially for small files. Unless somebody else is paying for this. Don't use Hadoop.)